# AngularJS: Waiting for Multiple asynchronous calls in a single function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I have an AngularJS function in which I am making 2 async calls. The 2 calls are not dependent but the function should only return when both calls are finished and result is stored in the return var.

I tried different solutions and ending up using the one shown below. But its very slow as its wait for the first one to finish

```
        function myAngularfunction(a, b) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var test= {
            a: "",
            b: ""
        };

        msGraph.getClient()
            .then((client) => {
                // First Async call
                client 
                .api("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/")
                .get()
                 .then((groupResponse) => {
                        var result = groupResponse;
                        test.a= result.displayName;

                        msGraph.getClient()
                            .then((client) => {
                                // Second Async call
                                client
                                    .api("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/")
                                    .get()
                                    .then((groupResponse) => {
                                        var result = groupResponse;
                                        test.b= result.displayName;
                                        defer.resolve(test);
                                    });

                            });

                    });
            });


        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Calling the function

```
myAngularfunction(a, b).then(function(obj)
```

How can I wait for the both calls in the same function with out nesting them? Or calling the next one without waiting for the first one to finish.

Comment: Why don't you use Promise.all ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try $when like this: $.when(functiton1,function2).done(()=>{}). but you need add deffered in function1 and function 2 .

Answer (score 0):

1. I think your situation is best suited to use `$q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then()` syntax.
2. You are calling `msGraph.getClient()` multiple times, I think this can be avoided.